# Could it be possible to observe an intermediate state of a final array during object creation?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, constructor, final

Imagine, that in my concurrent application I have a Java class like this (very simplified):

**Updated:**

```
public class Data {
    static Data instance;

    final int[] arr;

    public Data() {
        arr = new int[]{1, 0};
        arr[1] = 2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(() -> instance = new Data()).start();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(instance.arr));
    }
}
```

**Incorrect**:

```
public static class Data {
    final int[] arr;

    public Data() {
        arr = new int[]{1, 0};
        arr[1] = 2;
    }
}
```

Let's say one thread creates an object of this class and another thread that has a reference to this object reads values from an array `arr`.
Is it possible for second thread observe `1, 0` values of the array `arr`?

To check this case I've written test with JCStress framework (thanks for it to @AlekseyShipilev):

**Test seems incorrect as well** after comments below

```
@JCStressTest
@Outcome(id = "2, 1", expect = Expect.ACCEPTABLE, desc = "Seeing the set value.")
@Outcome(expect = Expect.FORBIDDEN, desc = "Other values are forbidden.")
@State
public class FinalArrayTest {

    Data data;

    public static class Data {
        final int[] arr;

        public Data() {
            arr = new int[]{1, 0};
            arr[1] = 2;
        }
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        data = new Data();
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(IntResult2 r) {
        Data d = this.data;
        if (d == null) {
            // Pretend we have seen the set value
            r.r1 = 2;
            r.r2 = 1;
        } else {
            r.r1 = d.arr[1];
            r.r2 = d.arr[0];
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine, second thread always observes last assignment  `arr[1] = 2`, but I still doubt, will I have the same result on all platforms like ARM?

All tests were executed on computer with this configuration:

- Number of cores: 4
- Java vendor: Oracle
- OS: Linux
- OS Version: 4.4.7-300.fc23.x86_64
- Java version: 9-ea+123
- OS Arch: amd64
- Number of test iterations: 10^10

Comment: Specifically, you're worried that the JIT might reorder the instructions of the other thread getting back the new `Data` reference and using it and that `Data` constructor doing the `arr[1] = 2;`? (Since the JIT is allowed to reorder things in some situations. And/or the compiler, I believe, but I think it's mostly the JIT.)

Comment: The reference to the object won't be set to the `data` variable until the object creation is done. You will therefore never see that `arr[1] == 0`.

Comment: @marstran: Since the compiler and/or JIT are allowed to reorder instructions, can you provide any references the back that up?

Comment: In this contrived example, is it possible the compiler optimizes the Data() constructor to the bytecode equivalent of `public Data() { arr = new int[]{1, 2}; }` ?

Comment: FWIW, I think [§17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) says that as long as the `Data` constructor doesn't provide a reference to the object it's constructing to any other thread, you're okay. But if I were sure, I'd be posting an answer. :-)

Comment: I'm looking for it :)

Comment: The JLS gives you the guarantee that all state accessed through a dereference chain rooted in a final field will be at least as up-to-date as of constructor completion.

Comment: I also have in mind this consideration, but **write** to the element with index 1 occurs after **write to the final** field. Will `arr` variable state _frozen_ after the first write or only after the second?

Comment: The freeze action happens at constructor completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axiomatic final field semantics is governed by a special happens-before rule. That rule is (a slide from my [JMM Pragmatics](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/jmm-pragmatics/#_part_v_finals), but most of the subsequent explanations there are due to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261287/vladimir-sitnikov):

[image]

Now. In the example when array element is modified after the initial store, here is how actions relate to the program:

```
public class FinalArrayTest {
    Data data;

    public static class Data {
        final int[] arr;

        public Data() {
            arr = new int[]{1, 0};
            arr[1] = 2; // (w)
        } // (F)
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor1() {
        data = new Data(); // (a)
    }

    @Actor
    public void actor2(IntResult1 r) {
        // ignore null pointers for brevity
        Data d = this.data; 
        int[] arr = d.arr; // (r1)
        r.r1 = arr[1]; // (r2) 
    }
}
```

`w hb F` and `F hb a` trivially. `a mc r1` (due to `a mc read(data)` and `read(data) dr read(data.arr)`. Finally, `r1 dr r2` because it is a dereference of array element. The construction is complete, and therefore write action `arr[1] = 2` happens-before read action `r.r1 = arr[1] (reads 2)`. In other words, this execution mandates seeing "2" in `arr[1]`.

Note: in order to prove that all executions are yielding "2", you have to prove that *no* execution can read the initial store to array element. In this case, it is almost trivial: there are no executions that can see the array element writes and bypass the freeze action. If there is a `this` "leakage", such an execution is trivially constructable.

Aside: note that it means that a final field store initialization order is irrelevant for final field guarantees, as long as nothing leaks. (This is what spec alludes to when saying *"It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are."*)

Comment: Great and complete explanation as always!

Comment: That particular sentence is one of the most confusing ones in the spec, and its relevance only becomes apparent when you start considering final field updates after construction, by "special mechanisms".

Comment: @AlekseyShipilev so if the reference will leak during object construction we could observe any intermediate state of `arr` field - [0,0] [1,0] or [1,2], am I right? That was this sentence describes: _"It will also see versions of any object or array referenced by those final fields that are at least as up-to-date as the final fields are."_

Comment: Plus, in that case the ordering between final field write and initialization of the referenced object _does_ matter.

Comment: @INIHELL Yes, if the reference leaks, you can trivially construct executions that read the array reference from the object field, and read whatever from array elements. This is a full-blown racy read, and all bets are off. No `final` would save you, because you bypass freeze actions in all these executions.

Answer (score 4):

> Let's say one thread creates an object of this class and another thread that has a reference to this object reads values from an array arr.

With the example as written, that is impossible until after the constructor returns.  The reference is not published by the constructor; i.e. it is safely published.

> Is it possible for second thread observe 1, 0 values of the array arr?

No.  Since the object is safely published, this [JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5). guarantee comes into play:

> *"An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields."*

By applying the rules of [JLS 17.5.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1), we can see that these guarantees extend to any fully encapsulated objects initialized by the constructor prior to the freeze at the end on the constructor body.

This is also described in more accessible terminology in *Goetz et al* "Java: Concurrency in Action".

---

If you were to change the example to this:

```
public static class Data {
    public static Data instance;

    final int[] arr;

    public Data() {
        instance = this;
        arr = new int[]{1, 0};
        arr[1] = 2;
    }
}
```

The statement I added changes everything.  Now some other thread could see a `Data` instance before the constructor completes.  It may then be able to see `arr[1]` in its intermediate state.

The "leakage" of the the reference to the `Data` instance while it it still being constructed is *unsafe publication*.

Comment: As T.J. Crowder answered to my similar comment above, do you have any references to back this up?

Comment: Goetz et al "Java Concurrency in Practice".  Chapter 16.2.2.

Comment: you are presuming safe publication of the instance?

Comment: In the OP's example, the instance >>is<< safely published.  I am not assuming / presuming anything.

Comment: Also, this behavior is covered by JLS 17.5 - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5, but the technical nature of the JLS means that it requires long and careful study to get your head around what Chapter 17 says.  Goetz et al is far more accessible.

Comment: If you start with the assumption of safe publication then the whole discussion is moot. Even without final fields everything would be safe. Final semantics additionally cover safety when publishing over a data race.

Comment: @StephenC you are totally right, my test wasn't correct, your code snippet illustrates situation that I tried to check:
[code snippet](http://pastebin.com/STpA5fBh)
So, if unsafe publication happened is it possible to observe 1,0 here?

Comment: Stephen's snippet is fundamentally different from yours because it leaks the object during construction. Your snippet is safe despite the unsafe publication over non-volatile field.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes that's right, that is what I've tried to ask, please excuse me for mixing these things, naturally my question was like this: if reference leak occurred to the object that was  constructed in a way that I described above, which state JLS allows us to observe

Comment: Your code sbows no reference leak from within the constructor, unlike Stephen's. Your code is safe and Stephen's isn't (as he points out).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yep, I updated code snippet, please check it  below **Updated** word

Comment: @StephenC so if we change the code like you described (please check the updated version in my question) what state we could see of `arr` variable?

Comment: @INlHELL - The example in your updated question is safe.  The assignment to `instance` happens after the `Data` constructor has completed.  You only get unsafe publication if you leak the reference **before** the constructor completes.